# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key

Tags: mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, migration

Hey guys I tried too much stuff and read some blogs or discussion I didn't fix my problem I'm new in laravel this project. I got error when I want to update a role on this error like

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
(`shop`.`permission_role`, CONSTRAINT
`permission_role_permission_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`permission_id`)
REFERENCES `permissions` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
(SQL: insert into `permission_role` (`permission_id`, `role_id`)
values (9, 17))
```

my migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('title')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    Schema::create('permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('title')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('role_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('roles')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');

        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');

        $table->primary(['role_id','user_id']);
    });

    Schema::create('permission_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('permission_id')->unsigned();


        $table->foreign('role_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('roles')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');

        $table->foreign('permission_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('permissions')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->primary(['permission_id','role_id']);
    });


}
```

my controller

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{

    $role=Role::create([
        'name'=>$request['name'],
        'title'=>$request['title'],
    ]);
    $role->permissions()->sync($request->input(['permission_id']));
    return redirect(route('role.index'));

}
```

view:

```
<select name="permission_id[]" id="" multiple > 
  @foreach($permissions as $permission) 
    <option value="{{$permission->id}}"> {{$permission->title}} </option> 
  @endforeach 
</select>
```

Comment: view
  <select name="permission_id[]" id=""  multiple >
@foreach($permissions as $permission)
<option value="{{$permission->id}}">
{{$permission->title}}
</option>
@endforeach
 </select>

Answer (score 1):

Your migrations for your pivots are adding composite primary keys:

```
$table->primary(['role_id','user_id']);
$table->primary(['permission_id','role_id']);
```

This is not the same as adding foreign keys.  You don't really need a primary key on those, but if you want one, I suggest you add it through the normal `increments` method:

```
$table->increments('id');
```

Try taking out those composite keys from the two pivot tables and re-run your migrations.  Then try to create a user again and add roles to that user.

Comment: when i use 'php artisan migrate:fresh' to save migration i get this error  :     SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `shop`.`permission_role` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `permission_role` add const
raint `permission_role_role_id_foreign` foreign key (`role_id`) references `roles` (`id`) on delete cascade)

Comment: Did you remove `$table->primary(['permission_id','role_id']);` from that table's migration?  If not, that would still be the problem (see first part of my answer).  If you did, the migration itself looks correct to me, but I would then ask, why tie the role to the permission?  Shouldn't it be `permission_user`?  That gets a little deeper into your architecture, but seems like a potential issue -- though I can't see it based on your code above.  Make sure the composite primary keys are gone - and try to `fresh` again.